# How to connect to an Oracle Database using cx_Oracle with service name and login?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a login, port number, host name and service name. How would I go about using the cx_Oracle.connect()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@host_name/service_name')
print con.version
con.close()
```

Comment: Do I not need a port number? And is it okay if the host and service name the same
?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me, you usually do need a port number

```
import cx_Oracle as orc 
user= 'username'
pwd = 'password'
host = 'url.or.path.to.db' #could look like path or url depending on where it's hosted
service_name = 'servicename'
portno = 1234 #note this is dummy port no

con = orc.connect(user, pwd, '{}:{}/{}'.format(host,portno,service_name))
```

Comment: Instead of the format(), it's arguably better to use makedsn(host, portno, service_name=service_name) so if cx_Oracle does any internal validations you get the benefit.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html?highlight=makedsn#cx_Oracle.makedsn

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used :

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@'service_name')
```

No need to used host name oracle can implicitly connect the host name you just give the service name what ever it is.